# Contextual meaning of "privilege"

Tags: meaning

I am not a native English speaker and have some confusion on the word *privilege*. I checked its meaning from the dictionary:

> a special right, advantage, or immunity granted or available only to a
>   particular person or group of people.

However when it's used in some contexts, I still can't get its exact meaning. For example, at the end of a remark, some people may say

> It is the **privilege** of my life to be here.

Why does he want to say it is the *special right* of his life to be here? Similarly, they say

> It is the **privilege** of my career to be chancellor of one of the
>   greatest universities in America.

Comment: It can also be a **gift** or **honor**.

Comment: What inferior dictionary has only that one definition for this word?

Comment: After going to the trouble of tidying up the layout here, I'm afraid I think it's General Reference that OP's citations are bordering on misuse anyway, but they don't conflict with other definitions as indicated by Alizter.

Comment: @Jasper: It looks like mine won out! I only started because I was niggled by the misspelling in the actual *title*, at which time I hadn't even read the question itself!

Answer (score 1):

In a way, the dictionary's definition applies. It is an advantage or good thing that not everyone has because not everyone gets to be there or be the chancellor. Perhaps this [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/privilege) might better apply: a chance to do something special.